# How to insert values into an MYSQL-DB via subselect?

Tags: sql, oracle, mysql

In oracle-db it is possible to insert values from table A to table B like

```
Insert into table_a values
 Select * from table_b where ID = 10
;
```

If the structures are the same.
How can I do this in MYSQL? My Editor gave me an sytanx-error.

Thx 4 your answers!

Greetz

Answer (score 0):

Mysql does not use the values keyword:

```
Insert into table_a (field1, field2)
 Select field1, field2 from table_b where table_b.ID = 10;
```

Comment: MySQL does use the values keyword

Comment: @JamesGoodwin the values keyword is not applicable since the values list is replaced by the select statement.

Answer (score 0):

In oracle and mysql:

```
insert into test 
select 1 from dual
```

Not: "insert into table *values*"